# Get dynamic tabs based on permission of user in struts2

Tags: jquery, plugins, struts2

I need to display tabs dynamically based on the users' permission as some user will have restriction for list of tabs. How can i do this in Struts2 or do we have any jquery plugin. The tabs can be n number and there can also be child tabs. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks anu.. Any way for me to get the tab list by iterating..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using this [jQuery tab plug-in](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/simple-tabs-w-css-jquery/) in my application. I have modified the html and jQuery code to display the default tab in order to display tab dynamically like you asked. Here it is what I did

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">

  <ul class="tabs">

        <li id="tab1head"><a href="#tab1">First heading</a></li>
        <li id="tab2head"><a href="#tab2">Second heading</a></li>
        <li id="tab3head"><a href="#tab3">Third heading</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab_container">

    <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
            content of tab1
        </div>
        <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
            content of tab2
        </div>
        <div id="tab3" class="tab_content">
            content of tab3
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

call the following function when you want to display a particular tab dynamically

```
function someFunction(tabheadID,tabID){
  $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");  
  $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
  $("#"+tabheadID).addClass("active").show(); //tabheadID may be tab1head etc
  $("#"+tabID).show();  //tabID may be tab1 etc
}
```

You can dynamically create a tab by using document.createElement() or equivalent jQuery syntax, apply appropriate classes and IDs and thean appending to the container div

Comment: Thanks anu.. Any way for me to get the tab list by iterating..?

Comment: @shree I didnt understand your question in the comment, can you explain what you want?

Comment: Hi Anu.. thanks for ur help. In the example u have given there are 3 tabs and First heading will be the tab value for first tab and the otehrs are similar. In this is there any way that i can get required number of tabs dynamically. I mean if i need 10 tabs in a page i don want to give 10 anchor tags.

Comment: hmm If you dont want to hard code `<li>` and `<a>` tags for each tab you can use `document.createElement()` as i mentioned. Make a function to create tabs using this way and pass number of tabs to create as arguements.

Answer (score 0):

This can be implemented By Role/and permission,
Just generate the proper list depending upon the User Role.

e.i:some role has permission on some perticular tab.So by executing query get the proper list.and Iterate in as **anu** defined in previous code.

```
<s:iterator list="%{tabs} name="eachTab">
    <li id="tab1head<s:property value="{eachTab.id}"/>">
      <a href="#tab1"><s:property value="{eachTab.tabeName}"/></a>
    </li> 
</s:iterator>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented tabs by creating a tld for checking the permission object and to display the tab values based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you have your permission framework setup, you can use struts conditional tags on the jsp to determine what is rendered.

```
<div class="tab_container">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
        content of tab1
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
        content of tab2
    </div>
    <s:if test="user.SuperUser">
         <div id="tab3" class="tab_content">
             content of tab3
         </div>
    </s:if>
</div>
```

In this example the user object simply has a boolean value of superUser which is called in the conditional. If the user.isSuperUser() == true, then tab3 is rendered on the jsp.